# Show $|X\times X| =$ cardinality of set of all functions $2\subseteq \omega \to X.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the Cartesian product of $X\times X$ has the same cardinality of the set of all functions from the set $2 \subseteq \omega$ to the set $X.$

I wonder what strategy should work for this problem.

For example, how can I find a function from one of these two sets to the other? I understand that the Cartesian product is a set of ordered pairs, as well as the other set. However, all I know about the last set is that it's contained in the power set of the Cartesian product of 2 with X (according to Halmos's book, Naive Set Theory).

Maybe if I can better define the last set I would be able to find a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "the set $2$ in $\omega$"?

Comment: @William: $2=\{0,1\}$; *in* here is $\subseteq$.

Comment: I guess I didn't need to say that 2 is in omega. But I meant that 2=1union{1}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The function $f:2\to X$ that takes $0$ to $x$ and $1$ to $y$ should correspond to the ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X$.

Comment: I'm stuck, I wonder if I have to split the proof in the cases where X is finite and infinite?

Comment: I'm thinking that each function in the set of functions defined above is a pair of ordered pairs (am I right?) of the form fk={(0,x),(1,y)}, with x and y in X. It's clear to me now that I have created |X|.|X| functions, which somehow translates into the idea of the cartesian product. What isn't clear to me is how I can see that as a bijection? I need a bijective function from that same set of functions into the cartesian product, but how since I wrote the set of functions as two ordered pairs and the cartesian product as one pair?

Comment: I suppose I can't define a function from {(0,x), (1,y)} to {(x,y)} which takes (0,x) to x and (1,y) to y?

Comment: @Samara: (Sorry to be so slow, but I was on the road.) There’s no need for separate cases. Your last comment is on the right track: your map should be $${}^2X\to X\times X:\big\{\langle 0,x\rangle,\langle 1,y\rangle\big\}\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$$ or its inverse, where ${}^2X$ is the set of functions from $2$ to $X$.